# Form still submits on preventDefault

Tags: forms, jquery, preventdefault

I am using jQuery to submit form data to a file in the form's action. However, when I submit the form, the browser redirects to the action (comment.php). I don't know why this is because `e.preventDefault()` should stop the browser's redirection. Ideally, I would like the browser to not redirect and remain on the current page (index.php).

jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
        $('.answerContainer').on('submit', 'form', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            $.post($(form).attr('action'), 
            $(form).serialize(), 
            function() {
                $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
                $('.commentBox').val('');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML Form:

```
<form method='POST' action='../comment.php'>
    //form contents
</form>
```

Comment: add `return false;` to your on submit function.

Comment: @Virendra where exactly should i add return false? after or before preventDefault?

Comment: @Virendra  no luck.  still redirects

Comment: try adding `onsubmit="return false;"` to your form.

Comment: @Virendra the page does not redirect, but now the data is not being placed in the database

Comment: I don't think your `selector` and `on` method is working correctly. Try: `$('form').on('submit', function(e) {` are you sure you have wrapped your form in a element with the class `answerContainer`??

Comment: @AndreasAL i tried your code and same result.  the form is inside the answerContainer class div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your `selector` and `on` method is working correctly. Try: `$('form').on('submit', function(e) {` are you sure you have wrapped your form in a element with the class `answerContainer`??

and then just to be sure don't use `$.post` use `$.ajax`:

and `this` inside an on i the element eg. `form` not the first selector `.answerContainer`.

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');

    $('.answerContainer').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            "url": $form.attr("action"),
            "data": $form.serialize(),
            "type": $form.attr("method"),
            "response": function() {
                $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
                $('.commentBox').val('');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: that was the solution.  im not sure what part of my code specifically wasn't working, but that was a great answer.  thank you very much

Comment: Im eater . But you had at least one error. `var form = $(this).closest("form").` should be `var form = $(this)`.

Comment: @user802370, Even though you are preventing the default form action, this line then goes on to submit the form:  `$.post($(form).attr('action'),`.  As stated in the answer, using `.ajax` rather than `.post` is what really fixes it.

Comment: @AndreasAL this is not part of the original question, but when i use your code the commentBox value doesnt clear.  it didn't clear when i used my code either, but any speculation as to why this happens? I double checked that textarea has the class commentBox