# JQuery val not changing

Tags: jquery

I have a page that inputs values of textareas into a mysql database.  Since this is a pseudo-submit I manually change the value of the textarea to nothing after the data is inputted.  however, after i press submit, the data is inputted properly, but the textarea does not clear. the html (below) is echoed several times depending on the number of answers.

Jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('document').ready(function(){

$('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');

 $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        "url": $form.attr("action"),
        "data": $form.serialize(),
        "type": $form.attr("method"),
        "response": function() {
            $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
            $('.commentBox').val(""); //this line doenst work
        }
    });
});
});



</script>
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class='commentBox'  wrap='soft' name='comment'></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='comment' class='submitCommentBox'>
```

Comment: [That one line of code](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr8m7/1/) works just fine.    Why aren't you using the `ajax` code in [the accepted answer of your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690117/form-still-submits-on-preventdefault)?

Comment: @Sparky672 i accidentally copied and pasted my previous code.  the code is now updated in my original question

Comment: Can you try `$('.commentBox').text("");`?

Comment: @AdamRackis thanks but doesnt work

Comment: @Sparky672 the one line of code doenst work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery not changing value of textarea after POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690724/jquery-not-changing-value-of-textarea-after-post)

Comment: Obviously, the line of code [works as demonstrated in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr8m7/1/).  The function is never being called because it's inside an invalid handler called `"response"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing `on`. It should be

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        success: function () {
            $(".commentContainer").load("../writecomment.php");
            $(".commentBox").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

What you are doing now is attaching a handler to every `.answerContainer` that lives inside a `form` (which is presumably all `.answerContainer`'s). That explains why the form submission stuff is happening once for every answer.

---

EDIT: I will try to make this clearer, since as per the comments you seem to have a hard time grasping what I'm trying to say. Very simply:

The following line is wrong:

```
$('.answerContainer').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
```

It should be:

```
$("form").on("submit", function (event) {
```

Comment: i updated my original question with my actual current code that still does not clear the .commentBox value

Comment: You are still misusing `on` in the same way you were before. You need to do `$("form").on("submit", ...)` not `(".answerContainer").on("submit", "form", ...)`.

Comment: i have update my code to reflect your answer however the .commentBox still does not clear after in run the code

Comment: Then you should ask a new question.

Comment: my updated code is now in this question.  i originally used .post (your solution), but it would redirect hte page to localhost/comment.php instead of just submitting the data and not refreshing the page.  i needed to use ajax.

Comment: If your updated code is now in this question, then you are STILL making the mistake. Please re-read my above comment as to which line is wrong. It has nothing to do with `post`; it has to do with `on`.

Comment: your solution is incorrect.  when i ran it, the browser rediects to localhost/comment.php.  you cannnot use .post.  instead you must use ajax as discussed in the previous quesition (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690117/form-still-submits-on-preventdefault) i asked about this code

Comment: Yet again you are discussing the wrong line of code. Whether you use `post` or `ajax` is not the underlying problem.

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned that i am using the on as described in your solution (updated in my original question) and the textareas still dont clear

Comment: Your question has mutated so much since its original form that any answers anyone has given have become worthless and out-of-date. Please ask a new question.

Comment: you're right. i asked a new question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690724/jquery-not-changing-value-of-textarea-after-post