# Jquery not changing value of textarea after POST

Tags: jquery

I have a page that inputs values of textareas into a MySQL database. Since this is a pseudo-submit I manually change the value of the textarea to nothing after the data is inputted. However, after I press submit, the data is inputted properly, but the textarea does not clear. The HTML (below) is echoed several times depending on the number of answers.

JavaScript:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');

    $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            "url": $form.attr("action"),
            "data": $form.serialize(),
            "type": $form.attr("method"),
            "response": function () {
                $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
                $('.commentBox').val(""); //this line doenst work
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class='commentBox'  wrap='soft' name='comment'></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='comment' class='submitCommentBox'>
```

Comment: Do you have a website online where I can see the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) does not take a `response` parameter in its options object. You should use

```
success: function () {
```

instead of

```
"response": function () {
```

Comment: But the question here are how to empty textarea propertly.

Comment: The textarea emptying code is correct, but the function to do so is never being called, because it is inside a function that jQuery ignores.

Comment: @domenic you are the man. thank you for your help. you're solution worked and ill accept it in 6 minutues when it lets me

Comment: +1, I did not notice that jQuery would end up forgetting that part of the code because it is spelled wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a pseudo-submit (as you put it), I would recommend taking it out of the context of a form altogether:

```
<textarea class='commentBox'  wrap='soft' name='comment'></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='comment' class='submitCommentBox'>
<script>
 $(".submitCommentBox").on("click", function (e) {
       var myComment = $(".commentBox").val();
       $.post("[YourUrl]",{comment:myComment},function(data){
          $('.commentBox').val("");
       });
    });
</script>
```